# Custom fields and logic in menu to create new Opportunity?

Tags: new, menu

I have some complicated subobject of opportunity (for quotes.)

When creating a new opportunity users wouldn't like to go through a new menu to create quotes.

They'd like to fill out some simple info such as the number of weeks people will be taking a course for and then have salesforce generate some dummy info for the quote.

Is this possible?

Comment: yes that is possible. This sounds like you might be able to complete this by using the process builder. Have you tried to review the process builder to see if this is a solution you can take advantage of before moving to code? https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/business_process_automation

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the approach you want. The easy go-to solution would be to complete the fields you want with a Process Builder like someone stated in a comment that way you can make sure that whenever a record is created, the fields you include are populated.

Another solution is to go for the visualforce solution: you can develop a small and quick VF with the fields you wish and make the controller do the rest for you. This would enable you to later add some more complex logic to the process and display a more enhanced interface.

Nonetheless, while possible, I recommend to ALWAYS try to elaborate solutions with Salesforce's standard tools, as a best practice.